# Thunderbird forward only most recent message from conversation

Tags: email, thunderbird

Sounds simple but I can't figure it out:

I have a lengthy email conversation chain. I would like to forward only the top (most recent) message to another person. I don't really want to have to delete all the other messages manually, because it would take a little bit of time, and I can already smell the formatting errors.

Is there a simple way of doing this without having to select all the other messages and deleting them by hand?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Deleting every message manually will be tough since `thunderbird` handles all the quotes as "one".

By default `thunderbird`will quote the **whole** original message if you choose to reply. However, you can **select** any text in a given mail and thunderbird will only quote the **selected** part.

For your problem: While viewing the (multi-part) conversation, try to mark **only** the latest answer (that you want to quote). Hit `Ctrl+R` **while the text is selected** and thunderbird will only paste the latest answer to your yet to be written reply

Comment: Thanks. It's somewhat tricky when there is a signature with graphics and other advanced formatting. This works good enough. To solve my problem, I hit forward, then I selected starting in the space between the most recent and other messages, and simply dragged all the way down and hit delete. It seemed to work just fine. Your way works great too. So the basic select mechanism seems smart enough to avoid formatting errors.